# How to create in Sql a table 10x100 with random numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, wordpress

I want to create in my database 3 tables 10x100 with random numbers. How could this be possible? Also I want in Wordpress site to give the user the option to choose what table he wants.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmfJc.jpg]

Comment: This post shows no effort or research on your part.

Comment: Because i am amateur i dont have any i idea how to solve this problem .

Comment: Do you know how to create a database table? Do you know how to insert rows into it? Do you know how to generate random numbers to insert into it? If not, I'd suggest you start by reading about those things (there are plenty of tutorials available). If so, can you be more specific about what part of that you need help with?

Comment: As a general suggestion, when you encounter a problem you have no idea how to solve, start by trying to break it down into smaller parts; figure out which part of those you know how to do and which parts you still need to learn.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read this.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/   and this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   It's hard to guess what you mean by "tables 10x100 with random numbers"  Do you mean tables with ten columns and 100 rows?  How will you use these tables?

Comment: I know how to create database table , and insert rows into it. My problem is how can i create a table 10x100 with random numbers. For example in excel i know the function =INT(250*RAND())+1 which gives you a random number. I don't know how to create this in Sql.

Comment: Yes i mean 100 columns and 100 rows. I want to create 3 of them with random numbers and after that i want to have the ability to choose one of them and connect with matlab and make data mining.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to serve custom data to a WordPress site. These should be two different questions. The first is how to create the DB tables you want. The second is how to display custom data on a WordPress page. Both of those can be handled by some introductory material. I think the heart of what you are looking for is the RAND() function.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Comment: Please avoid linking to second-rate knock-offs of third-rate sites like w3schools. The [official documentation on `RAND()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand) is the best place to go.